# Most efficient way to calculate and remove overlapping timelines from one timeline in Spotfire

Tags: python, ironpython, calculated-columns, spotfire, terr

I have a question about timelines in Spotfire.

I have a script that takes two timelines from several machines and tasks.

-One timeline shows all the task times from several tasks per machine
-One timeline shows the issues that occurred per machine.

With this data it will calculate the overlap time where the issues overlap with the task time, it does this per task per machine.

The script (TERR script) that i use now takes about 30+ minutes to calculate (the amount of data is over 100.000 lines)
This is to much time and to much strain on the servers as well.

is there any way, perhaps not with a script but only with calculated columns (where you can intersect over the correct machine/tasks?) to do this more efficiently ?

This is an example of the outcome i'm looking for:

| Task Start | Task Stop | Issue Start | Issue Stop | Overlap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-20 20:00 | 2023-06-21 01:00 | 2023-06-20 21:00 | 2023-06-20 22:00 | 60 |
| 2023-06-20 20:00 | 2023-06-21 01:00 | 2023-06-20 23:00 | 2023-06-21 00:30 | 90 |
| 2023-06-21 23:00 | 2023-06-22 02:00 | 2023-06-21 22:30 | 2023-06-22 00:30 | 90 |
| 2023-06-21 23:00 | 2023-06-22 02:00 | 2023-06-22 00:30 | 2023-06-22 01:30 | 60 |

this is a very simple table because it also needs to take in account the separate tasks and machines.

Hopefully someone can find a better solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to calculate the overlap column?
Can you try this:

```
case  when not (([Issue Stop]<[Task Start]) or ([Issue Start]>[Task Stop])) then 
  DateDiff('minute',Max([Task Start],[Issue Start]),Min([Task Stop],[Issue Stop]))
else 0.0 end
```

Comment: Hi Gaia, thanks for your answer, it seems very promissing allthough the values columns that this calculation needs to go through are not on the same line, i'm thinking of using an  (Intersect([common value],AllPrevious(Task Start))) calculation to fill in the Task Start and Stop values on the same line as the issue start and stop times but i do not know how accurate it is, do you know an accurate way of doing this ?

Comment: can you clarify the desired goal? Your overlap column seemed to be one for each line. I can see that a task can extend over multiple lines. So what is the final result you want and how is it going to be displayed?

Comment: the report shows a column with the total calculated times for the tasks and the lost times. the lost times needs to be subtracted from the task times when they overlap so we can show the real amount of the task time instead of when the task was still running but the machine not operational due to an issue. Unfortunately there is no relation between the task time and the issues (these are seperate datatables)other then the machine name, this is why i need to make a relation between the columns and show the task start and stop times when the issue times are in this range

Comment: is it possible to post a realistic sample dataset (or two datasets) as you see it at the start? Including the machine name for a couple of machines? Your test dataset looks rather straightforward, so it is difficult to work out what the actual problem is.

Comment: where can i post that ? i think i solved all issues with intersect to get the connect start and stop calues related to the columns but when a issue spans over multiple days it will duplicate itself and causes multiple lines that all get processed in the calculation, i need to find a way to remove these duplicate values in the calculation

Comment: a couple of screenshots would be fine, I guess. Is the problem actually in joining the tables or in the calculation?